# Emirates luggage size rules changed since Nov.15, 2014

Tags: luggage, emirates

According to http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/baggages.aspx,

> **For tickets issued on or after November 15, 2014**
>
> Total dimensions (length + width + height) of each piece must not
>   exceed 150 cm (59 inches). Customers with individual items exceeding
>   above dimensions up to 300 cm (118 inches) will be charged an
>   additional fee. Individual items with total dimensions exceeding 300
>   cm (118 inches) cannot be transported as checked baggage and must be
>   sent as cargo or freight.
>
> For customers with two pieces of luggage in all three classes, the
>   total combined dimensions of both pieces should not exceed 300 cm (118
>   inches).
>
> **For tickets issued prior to November 15, 2014**
>
> Total dimensions (length+ width+ height) of each piece must not exceed
>   158 cm (62 inches). For Economy Class customers with two pieces of
>   luggage, the total combined dimensions of both pieces must not exceed
>   273 cm (107 inches). Customers with baggage exceeding these dimensions
>   will be charged an additional fee.

I'm allowed 2 bags, and I have two bags that measure 158cm. Since Nov.15, 2014, the max size allowed has been reduced from 158cm to 150cm. How strictly are the new rules enforced? Do I need to buy new bags just for this one flight? I couldn't find any info about the fees for luggage that violates size restrictions.

Comment: Oversized bags go as cargo: http://www.emirates.com/us/english/help/faq/490107/weight-and-piece-concept .... @pnuts, I have seen tape measures used at check in (though not specifically Emirates)

Comment: Thanks pnuts and Tom. @Tom, from your link: **Individual items** with total dimensions exceeding 300cm (118 inches) cannot be transported as checked baggage and must be sent as cargo or freight. Since my individual item does not exceed 300cm, I'm not sure it will be sent as cargo. In any case, I'm still not sure if its worth buying two new bags.

Comment: @elexhobby - (oops, must have been seeing inches and thinking cms) But I think the keywords in link are "no exceptions to this rule" attached to the post Nov 15 rules.  As they have reduced the allowable size and added the no exceptions to other rules, I would be prepared for them to enforce the new rule (especially since these are relatively new changes).  You may need to call and ask what the oversized baggage fee would be for your particular flights.

Comment: @pnuts - have seen measuring tapes in both Asia and the Americas.  Have had my big roller duffel measured numerous times, then ignored because of my FF status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good reason carry on luggage is measured by putting in a bin (which btw is always a little bigger actually than advertised). Your luggage is not a right cuboid and measuring it precisely is very hard. This is only a guess but I bet they will let 8 cm slide... provided your bag is indeed 150cm. Does that include handles? Wheels? And so on. In short: if I were flying Emirates a lot and my luggage is not expensive then but only then would I buy new luggage.